# Error : Could not found installable ISAM vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am using VS2015 and MS Access.
Error : Could not found installable ISAM

```
Dim cons As String = "provider= Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=D:\Users\rjimenez\Documents\QAdatabase.mdb"
```

What I need to do?

Comment: Jet is only available in 32-bit. Your project must target the x86 platform or else target Any CPU and have the Prefer 32-bit box checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this connection

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=D:\Users\rjimenez\Documents\QAdatabase.mdb;user id=admin;password=;"
```